# What is best to hold information while being able to sort it also?

Tags: list, sorting

So to give you guys a bit of insight, I need a way to hold information all together if possible in the format of:

**String Int Int Int Int**

**String Int Int Int Int**

**String Int Int Int Int**

Essentially making it a table. This data will also be sorted by the integer in the last column so the highest value at the top.
I've been thinking of the best and simplest way to do this but I just cant put my finger on it. I was thinking about 2D arrays, Objects and Hash Maps but don't know what is the best when it comes to simplicity and efficiency to sort data.

Any ideas of which way would be best to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're working with, I would say either make a custom class containing properties matching those columns, or use a `Tuple<string, int, int, int, int>`, and then put those in a `List<T>`.

Whether you use a class or a Tuple you'll be able to sort based on any or multiple properties.